# Software for drawing biomolecules (with functional groups abbreviated)

Tags: software

I'm sorry if this is OT, but I find myself slowly going insane trying to draw common biomolecules such as Acetyl Coenzym A. The thing is, I just want to draw the acetyl part and then link that to a text that says "coenzym A" (or whatever), so something like this:

[image]

I have no need for the gigantic structure of actual Coenzyme A. I'm trying to visualize basic metabolic reactions such as the citric acid cycle etc. Having a 20-molecule-chain in every other step would just be distracting.

The software I've come across thus far don't support the typing part of the molecule as free text, they require me to pick an actual molecule from the periodic table. In the few cases where I can type text I can't have the molecule link to it.

Thus far I have tried chem4word 3.1 (only supports pre-defined functional groups), Pubchem sketcher 2.4, chemspace and Molview.

Comment: [Resources for learning Chemistry — Software](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37880/41328). ChemDraw and MarvinSketch both can do what you are asking about, both as label or as a functional group. [chem*f*ig](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) allows to draw literally whatever you want in your $\mathrm\LaTeX$ document, Rmd file or exported PDF/image.

Comment: What is "*OT*" BTW?

Comment: Of Topic, other stackexchange sites tend to frown upon questions that don't have a specific answer (so what is the best software is considered a bad question since that's subjective)

Comment: Sounds related to the «HELM toolbar» Pierre Morieux/ChemDraw Wizard presented in his installment 4 about ChemDraw (around 9:17 mm:ss) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkkpuW322qo).  If done *right*, such a shortcut retains chemical meaning (i.e., offering an expansion from a mere string «CoA» to the corresponding structure *if* needed).

Comment: ACD labs ChemSketch is available in a limited freeware version that has this capability if you don’t want to pay for something more powerful